# Apply element selector to class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style an element that has a class exactly like a h3 element. Is there anything like an `@apply` directive in CSS? Because I don't want to add the class to the selector of h3, because the CSS is only conditionally loaded.

This is what I imagine:

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    /* ... */
}

/* somewhere else */
.my-class {
    @apply h1;
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: The whole point of class in css is so you can reuse it. Add the class to the tag, if your css is not loaded then the class won't have any effect, if the css is loaded then your class rules would apply. If your use case is somehow more complex, please describe it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. As you suggest only a selector list, as in

```
h3, .my-class {
  /* ... */
}
```

could be use.

A preprocessor (such as SASS or LESS) could be used, but those will only result in the same syntax in the end.

Answer (score 0):

As you were told below, this is not possible, but if the H3 class name is "class1", you can do the following:

```css
.class1 {
padding: 3px;
color: red;
}

.class1.example {
padding: 8px;
color: green;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="class1">EXAMPLE</h3>
<p class="class1 example">EXAMPLE 2</p>
```